# Rails - Add to Association through table or select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, activerecord

I'm new to Rails world, so I'm trying to do some sample apps to learn even more. I'm stuck and I would appreciate any help. I looked for some similar question without success. But I think there's one somewhere.

The case is: I Have a Cake model that has_many Ingredients Through Recipes. Creating, Editing, Deleting is Ok, the basics I already learned. But I want to, while creating(or editing) a Cake, be able to see all Ingredients already in that recipe (Done) and choose from a "select" or a table(listing, thats the case below) any Ingredient I want to add or remove from Recipe. Doing all this without commit to database and not reloading the page (Ajax). Then when I click "Save cake" everything is commited to Database. I made myself clear?

Below is what I did till now:

*routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :cakes do
    resources :ingredients do
      member do
        get 'add', to: 'cakes#add'
        get 'remove', to: 'cakes#remove'
      end  
    end  
  end  

  resources :ingredients 

end
```

*cake.rb*

```
class Cake < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipes
end
```

*ingredient.rb*

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes
  has_many :cakes, through: :recipes
end
```

*recipe.rb*

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cake
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

*cakes_controller.tb*

```
class CakesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cake, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_ingredients, only: [:new, :edit]

  def index
    @cakes = Cake.all
  end

  def show

  end

  def new
    @cake = Cake.new
  end

  def edit

  end

  def create
    @cake = Cake.new(cake_params)
    @cake.save
    redirect_to cakes_path
  end

    private
          def cake_params
            params.require(:cake).permit(:name)
          end

          def set_cake
            @cake = Cake.find(params[:id])
            @used_ingredients = @cake.ingredients
          end

          def set_ingredients
            @ingredients = Ingredient.all
          end

end
```

*Form to cake - _form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for @cake do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name%>
</p>
<div id="used ingredients" >
    <%= render 'recipe_ingredients'%>
</div>
<div id="available ingredients" >
    <%= render 'available_ingredients'%>
</div>
<p>
    <%= f.submit%>
</p>
<% end %>
```

*Ingredients already on recipe - _recipe_ingredients.html.erb*

```
<table border="1px">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Used Ingredients</th>
</tr>

<% @used_ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
    <tr>
        <td> <%= ingredient.name %> </td>
        <td> <%= link_to 'Remove', remove_cake_ingredient_path(@cake,ingredient), remote: true %> </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>

</table>
```

*Ingredients available - _available_ingredients.html.erb*

```
<table border="1px">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Available Ingredients</th>
</tr>

<% @ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
    <tr>
        <td> <%= ingredient.name %> </td>
        <td> <%= link_to 'Add', add_cake_ingredient_path(@cake,ingredient), remote: true %> </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>

</table>
```

Here is where I'm stuck, how to add or remove items from @cake.ingredients without committing on database and reload the recipe ingredients list without reload the page (in fact, reload the list I know how to do, through JS rendering the partial again, that's ok.).
But the trick here is click on the "Add" or "Remove" link, add or remove an ingredient to/from recipe and only commit after "Save Cake" submit button. Or cancel any changes if the user change his mind. That's why I need to work on the object lists, not database directly.

Anyone could help me?

PS.: 1 - I know that remote:true on links will fire a action.js.erb file. That's clear to me. The problem is I couldn't work with the same object (@cake.recipes) on every add/remove link click. On another test I made a global hash $ingredients, but I don't think that's the Rubier mode.

2 - I made a table(grid) with all available ingredients, but it culd be a select or collection_select, but I don't want to use the multiple:true option

3 - Maybe there is some Gem that do what I need, if anyone could know.

Answer (score 0):

Luciano,

Why couldn't you create a cake and then the process of adding ingredients will result in incremental changes in your db?  Why does it all have to be complete client side (and increasing the risk of the user loosing their work).

If you want to do it client side, then avoid the trips to the back end until you are ready to commit.  You will have to provide JS to dynamically add form elements as the user selects them.

To answer your questions:
1) Do not use the global... not only is it not Ruby.. it will never work if you have more than one user.  You are free to use the session if you want however but it is generally a discouraged practice and not needed in your case.  If you build your model incrementally as described above, you avoid this entirely.

2) Take a look at 'chosen' js select.. it is very powerful and I believe it will satisfy your requirements

3) Try to avoid using gems when you are first learning Rails.  The staggering amount of gems found on big project teams makes it increasingly difficult for new team members to come up to speed. Most projects have hundreds of gems but usually most are known (or almost default) for some applications.

Comment: Hi ilan berci Thank you so much for your answer.
There's no problem in saving directly on db. But as I'am learning and I problably know how to do that, I was trying to do something I have no ideia how to achieve.
1 - I supposed that, in fact, is not beauty at all.
2 - Thanks, that seem great.
3 - Got it.

Comment: By the way as I'm changing from Desk(Delphi/ VS) dev to Web, I need to learn again everything I know, even more about ruby/rails as it have another perspective about developing. For example, I'm not 100% sure if I made my models and associations the right way. It seems more logical a cake having many or one(depending on POV) recipes and each recipe having many ingredients, so I think I would need another join model with recipes and ingredients.
That's why I came here and asked this question, to see if I'm going to the right way and trying to do something I don't know how to start.